# How can I add two different auto increment numbers to same column in PHP & MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

```
mysql_select_db('bestfood123');
$user=$_POST['t4'];

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM login WHERE username='$user'");

$info = mysql_fetch_array($result);


if($info['section']=="delhi")
{
  mysql_query("insert into support values('a.','$status','$sbj','$message','$userid','$user','','','$date')");
  printf("<h2>your incident id is: %d\n</h2>", mysql_insert_id());    
  $inci=mysql_insert_id();
}
else
{     
  mysql_select_db('bestfood123');

  mysql_query("insert into support  values('b.','$status','$sbj','$message','$userid','$user','','','$date')");
  printf("<h2>your incident id is: %d\n</h2>", mysql_insert_id());    
  $inci=mysql_insert_id();
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't need the second `mysql_select_db()`.

Comment: You shouldn't 1) call `mysql_select_db('bestfood123');` after `else` 2) insert $_POST to query without `mysql_escape_string()` 3) use same code twice if only 1 variable changes

Answer (score 0):

> How can i add two diffrent auto incrment no. to same column in php
>   mysql

You can't create 2 primary keys in 1 table.

Comment: i want to add two diffrent auto increment index in same column?

Comment: You can create 2 field with same auto_increment `ALTER TABLE test ADD PRIMARY KEY (x, qnt);` Also You can write `TRIGGER`, which will update some value `ON INSERT`

Comment: i want my index show like this 10001,10002,10003 and in same column with some condition true it strt lyk 20001,20002,20003

Comment: that's not an index at all that so. You just need a column with different values :) But I think You can look at this side: create 1 column with primary index and auto_increment and a column near with some flag, for example `MYCOND` ENUM('Y','N'). This way You can use all features of A_I field and select what You need by add some condition (Like `AND MYCOND='Y'`)

Comment: can u tell me the actual syntax of using "enum" in insert into table value?

Comment: for example You have 3 fields: `ID (INT, A_I, NULL), IS_SUPER(ENUM, 'Y','N'), ITEM(VARCHAR, 255)`. Inserting: `INSERT INTO mytable (IS_SUPER, ITEM) VALUES ('Y','beer'),('N','milk');`

Comment: i got another solution for this problem...mysql_query("insert into support values('null','$status','$sbj','$message','$userid','$user','','','$date','')",$dbc) or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  $index=mysql_insert_id();
  $inci='1'.$index;
  echo "$inci";
mysql_query("UPDATE support SET incidentno='$inci' WHERE index='$index'",$dbc) or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  printf("<h2>your incident id is: %d\n</h2>", $inci) ;
  echo $inci; bt this is showing mysql error

Comment: You use second query for update one more cell, but can use trigger. It'll automate this action

Comment: [How to create trigger in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html)

Comment: thnx for helping me.. i have put trigger mysql_query("CREATE TRIGGER `bestfood123`.`support` after INSERT on `bestfood123`.`support` FOR EACH ROW UPDATE support SET incidentno='$inci'WHERE index='$index'") or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); bt it z again showing error Could not connect: Can't update table 'support' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

Comment: drop old triggers before add one more

Comment: This is my frst trigger. i cant get the actual syntax of trigger? can you tell me the proper syntax? the function of insertion is also i have to put in trigger?